# Why piped arguments to date command are not correctly processed?

Tags: date

I have the problem illustrated in the following code snippet:

```
$ echo "2014-10-26 23:24:38.3123123" | date -d -
Sun Oct 26 00:00:00 EDT 2014
$ date -d "2014-10-26 23:24:38.3123123"
Sun Oct 26 23:24:38 EDT 2014
```

As you can see, the hour/min/seconds information is not picked up when I pipe in data with `echo`, but it is picked up when I use it as a command line argument. I am sure that there is something dumb I am not noticing, but if anyone can enlighten me on what that is it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
$ echo "2014-10-26 23:24:38.3123123" | date -d -
```

The space character between `2014-10-26` and `23:24:38.3123123` is treated like an argument separator and the date command takes the date string as two different arguments.

You can simply escape this space character:

```
    $ echo "2014-10-26\ 23:24:38.3123123" | date -d -
```

and it works;

```
Sun Oct 26 23:24:38 EDT 2014
```